# Commutative diagram in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

During my study of linear algebra, I have learnt that the following holds for every linear operator $\mathcal{A}$ on given vector space $V$

- If $\alpha:V\longrightarrow V^{**}$ is natural isomorphism, then $\mathcal{A}^{**}\alpha=\alpha\mathcal{A}$;
- If $\phi:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphism (which depends on basis), then $A\phi=\phi \mathcal{A},$ where $A$ is matrix obtained by $\mathcal{A}e_i=A_i^je_j$;

And there are more examples, of course. So, here I see a pattern: given two linear operators $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$, isomorphism $f$ between two vector spaces $V, W$ and relation $\mathcal{A}\phi=\phi\mathcal{B}$ we can somehow "identify" $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ despite the fact, that they are different object acting on different spaces.

Also I have encountered such relations in representation theory in definition of representation homomorphism.

I am interested why commutation relations commonly occur in math. I have heard of category theory and i have seen commutative diagrams, but I know nothing about this topic.

Comment: This always happens when you have two operations that you want to be compatible. For example, the integers have addition and multiplicaton, but what makes the integers into a ring is that these two operations are compatible by distributivity, which can be written as a commutative diagram. Your question is too open ended I think. Asking why commutative diagrams appear in math is almost like asking why equations appear in math. Do you have a particular example of something you want to understand?

Comment: I identify with this question.  For example, I never really understood what was being done when elements of $V$ are identified with elements of $V^\ast$ using an inner product, for example, and I think that's part of this.

Comment: _they are different object acting on different spaces._ This has very much to do with category theory. I think you would benefit a lot by seeking out some very basic introductions to equivalences and adjoints in category theory.

Comment: I’ve seen equations of the form $g\varphi=\varphi f$ *a lot*. They occur all over the place in abstract algebra but also in topology and the theory of (measure-preserving) dynamical systems. I once saw it called, and for ever after like to call it, “intertwining”. You have some process on one system $f$, a process $g$ on another system, and you want to define what a homomorphism (a system-compatible relation) between them might be. The standard definition shall be, any map $\varphi$ that intertwines $f,g$ as above. I’ve seen it said that the systems are “conjugate” when such $\varphi$ exist

Comment: And I second the other comments. To appreciate the utility of commutative diagrams in general terms you’d benefit from looking at natural transformations and some low-level category theory. In specific terms, commutative diagrams are just a nice way of describing relations and discovering tools you can use to facilitate the algebra. A problem in $\mathcal{B}$ might be more easily solved if I use my diagram to get a problem involving $\mathcal{A}$, one which is better understood.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz The problem is that it's hard for me to formulate the question, because I am not familiar with this subject. So, let me put it this way: why do we use these commutative relations, when we want to identify objects? For example, operators acting on different spaces. Why is it a proper way of "identification"? Or is it just postulates?

Comment: @rschwieb Would you mind recommending something to read on this topic? I have heard only about Mac Lane book.

Comment: Emily Riehl's category theory in context, Tom Leinster's an Basic category theory, Harold Simmons' An introduction to category theory.

Comment: @Motoko Alas, MacLane's book is far too... something-or-another.  I _did_ very much enjoy Leinster's book.  I had started on Riehl's book, and it is excellent with lots of examples I didn't find elsewhere, but it felt like slow going.  I do intend to continue on it again in the future though.  IMO Leinster's book is a great place to start.

Comment: @FShrike I expect that a great deal of intertwining is just a reflection of some commutative square expressing naturality of a equivalence of functors.

Comment: Leinster’s book is excellent as it covers very well the essentials and doesn’t frighten the reader with the more advanced category theory only useful for more specialised topics